# SQL Server 2016 High Scan counts in spite of non Clustered indexes with covering indexes

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan, ssrs-2016

I have a download stored procedure that gets called when an SSRS gets downloaded. 
I have indexes on the table that cover the fields on the tables involved.

But there are clustered index scans on Feedback and ApplicationUser tables. I need to reduce the scans, and I have already updated the stats on the table. There isn't enough defrag on the tables to have caused this.

This query needs to run in under 30 seconds but is taking a minute and 40 currently. Can you please help?

[Execution PLan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/feafz1r6gul393p/trailgap.sqlplan?dl=0)

```
USE [BOB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_TrailGapReportDownload]    Script Date: 3/7/2018 10:25:45 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_TrailGapReportDownload]
(
   @ProductGroup NVARCHAR(200) = ''
  ,@Region NVARCHAR(100) = ''
  ,@State NVARCHAR(100) = ''
  ,@City NVARCHAR(100) = ''
  ,@BOMBucket bigint = NULL
  ,@Agency NVARCHAR(200) = ''
  ,@Agent NVARCHAR(200) = ''   
)
--exec usp_TrailGapReportDownload '','','','',NULL,'',''
--exec usp_TrailGapReportDownload '','BURDWAN REGION','','',0,'39e24168319ef3b2220c9c2394e35f50',''
-- exec usp_TrailGapReportDownload '','','','GANGTOK',0,'',''
--exec usp_TrailGapReportDownload '','','','ABOHAR',6,'',''
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),  
        @paramlist  NVARCHAR(4000), 
        @nl CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = '

            ;WITH trailsCTE AS(

                select *
                from 
                    (select 
                        Rn=row_number()over (partition by acc.AGREEMENTID order by (select 1))
                        ,f.DispositionCode
                        ,acc.BUCKET,acc.CURRENT_BUCKET
                        ,acc.AGREEMENTID as AccountNumber
                        ,acc.NPA_STAGEID AS NPAFlag
                        ,acc.PRODUCT
                        ,acc.ProductGroup
                        ,acc.BRANCH  as BRANCHAlpha
                        ,acc.ZONE as ZONE
                        ,acc.Region as REGION
                        ,acc.State  as State
                        ,acc.CITY as CITY 
                        ,acc.CUSTOMERNAME as [Account Owner]
                        ,(AccOwner.FirstName+'' ''+ AccOwner.LastName) as AllocationOwnerName
                        ,ds.Name as AllocationOwnerRole
                        ,AccOwner.CustomId as AllocationOwnerCode
                        ,TelAgency.FirstName as TeleCallingAgencyName
                        ,TelAgency.CustomId as TeleCallingAgencyCode
                        ,(telAgent.FirstName+'' ''+ telAgent.LastName) as TeleCallerName
                        ,telAgent.CustomId as TeleCallerCode
                        ,FieldAgency.FirstName as FiedAgencyName
                        ,FieldAgency.Id as FiedAgencyId
                        ,FieldAgency.CustomId as FiedAgencyCode
                        ,(FieldAgent.FirstName+'' ''+ FieldAgent.LastName) as FieldAgentName
                        ,FieldAgent.Id as FieldAgentId
                        ,FieldAgent.CustomId as FieldAgentCode
                        ,[Primary Allocation status for Tele-calling Agency] = iif(TelAgency.CustomId is null, ''GAP'',''Allocated'')
                        ,[Primary Allocation status for Field Agency]= iif(FieldAgency.CustomId is null, ''GAP'',''Allocated'')
                        ,[Secondary allocation Status for tele-Calling agent]=iif(telAgent.CustomId is null, ''GAP'',''Allocated'')
                        ,[Secondary allocation Status for field agent]=iif(FieldAgent.CustomId is null, ''GAP'',''Allocated'')
                        ,acc.CUSTOMERNAME
                        ,convert(date,(select top 1 CreatedDate from Collections WHERE Collections.AccountId=Acc.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)) AS LastPaymentDate
                        ,convert(date,(select top 1 PTPDate from Feedback f WHERE  f.AccountId=Acc.Id ORDER BY PTPDate DESC)) AS LastPTPDate
                        ,convert(date,(select top 1 DispositionDate from Feedback f WHERE f.AccountId=Acc.Id ORDER BY DispositionDate DESC)) AS LastDispositionDate
                        ,(select top 1 DispositionGroup from Feedback f WHERE f.AccountId=Acc.Id ORDER BY DispositionDate DESC) AS LastDispositionCodeGroup
                        ,(select top 1 DispositionCode from Feedback f WHERE f.AccountId=Acc.Id ORDER BY DispositionDate DESC) AS LastDispositionCode
                        --,convert(date,F.DispositionDate) AS LastDispositionDate
                        ,dbo.getDispositionCodeGroupFromDispostionCode(F.DispositionCode) AS [Current Disposition code group]
                        ,F.DispositionCode AS [Current Disposition code]
                        ,(Feedcollector.FirstName+'' ''+ Feedcollector.LastName) as CollectorName
                        ,Feedcollector.CustomId as CollectCode
                        ,RightPartyContact
                        ,PTPAmount 
                        ,convert(date,f.PTPDate) as PTPDate
                        ,AssignTo
                        ,AssignReason as ReasonForAssigning
                        ,IsReallocationRequest as ReallocationRequest
                        ,ReallocationRequestReason as ReallocationReason
                        ,NewArea as NewArea
                        ,NewAddress as NewAddress
                        ,f.State as NewState
                        ,f.City as NewCity
                        ,NewContactNo as NewContactNumber
                        ,NewEmailId as NewEmailID
                        ,f.Remarks 
                        ,NextAction
                        ,NonPaymentReason as ReasonForNonPayment
                        ,PickAddress as PickUpAddress
                        ,DispositionDate
                        ,[Trail Status]= iif((TelAgency.CustomId is null AND FieldAgency.CustomId is null AND telAgent.CustomId is null AND FieldAgent.CustomId is null),''NA'',
                                         iif(TelAgency.CustomId is not null OR FieldAgency.CustomId is not null OR telAgent.CustomId is not null OR FieldAgent.CustomId is not null
                                              and f.DispositionCode is null,''Gap'',''Trail Received'')) 
                        from LoanAccounts acc                    
                        left outer join Feedback F ON F.AccountId=acc.ID
                        left outer join ApplicationOrg TelAgency on TelAgency.id=acc.TeleCallingAgencyId
                        left outer join ApplicationUser telAgent on telAgent.id=acc.TeleCallerId
                        left outer join ApplicationOrg FieldAgency on FieldAgency.id=acc.AgencyId
                        left outer join ApplicationUser FieldAgent on FieldAgent.id=acc.CollectorId
                        left outer join ApplicationUser Feedcollector on Feedcollector.id=f.CollectorId
                        left outer join ApplicationUser AccOwner on AccOwner.id=acc.AllocationOwnerId
                        left outer join CompanyUserDesignation com on AccOwner.id=com.CompanyUserId
                        left outer join Designation ds on ds.id=com.DesignationId )x where x.Rn=1)

                    select                   
                    AccountNumber,NPAFlag,PRODUCT=dbo.getProductNameFromCode(PRODUCT),
                    [BOM Bucket]=t.BUCKET,[Current Bucket]=t.CURRENT_BUCKET,
                    BRANCHAlpha,ZONE,REGION,State,CITY,
                    [Account Owner],AllocationOwnerName,AllocationOwnerRole,AllocationOwnerCode,
                    TeleCallingAgencyName,TeleCallingAgencyCode,TeleCallerName,TeleCallerCode,
                    FiedAgencyName,FiedAgencyCode,FieldAgentName,FieldAgentCode,
                    [Primary Allocation status for Tele-calling Agency],[Primary Allocation status for Field Agency],
                    [Secondary allocation Status for tele-Calling agent],[Secondary allocation Status for field agent],
                    CUSTOMERNAME,LastPaymentDate,LastPTPDate,LastDispositionDate,
                    LastDispositionCodeGroup=dbo.getDispositionCodeGroupFromDispostionCode(LastDispositionCode),LastDispositionCode,
                    [Current Disposition code group],[Current Disposition code],
                    CollectorName,CollectCode,RightPartyContact,PTPAmount,PTPDate,AssignTo,ReasonForAssigning,
                    ReallocationRequest,ReallocationReason,NewArea,NewAddress,NewState,NewCity,NewContactNumber,NewEmailID,
                    Remarks,NextAction,ReasonForNonPayment,PickUpAddress,DispositionDate,[Trail Status]
                    from trailsCTE t WHERE 1=1 AND t.[FieldAgentId] IS NOT NULL '  + @nl

IF @ProductGroup != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.ProductGroup = @ProductGroup' + @nl
IF @Region != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.Region = @Region' + @nl
IF @State != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.STATE = @State' + @nl
IF @City != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.City = @City' + @nl
IF @BOMBucket IS NOT NULL SELECT @sql += ' AND t.BUCKET = @BOMBucket' + @nl
IF @Agency != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.[FiedAgencyId] = @Agency' + @nl
IF @Agent != '' SELECT @sql += ' AND t.[FieldAgentId] = @Agent' + @nl

print @sql

SELECT @paramlist = '
      @ProductGroup NVARCHAR(200)
      ,@Region NVARCHAR(100)
      ,@State NVARCHAR(100)
      ,@City NVARCHAR(100)
      ,@BOMBucket bigint
      ,@Agency NVARCHAR(200)
      ,@Agent NVARCHAR(200)    
     '
    EXEC sp_executesql 
       @sql
      ,@paramlist
      ,@ProductGroup     
      ,@Region
      ,@State
      ,@City
      ,@BOMBucket     
      ,@Agency
      ,@Agent 

END
GO


Table 'Feedback'. Scan count 1065818, logical reads 10626649, physical reads 9, read-ahead reads 20931, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'Collections'. Scan count 223, logical reads 1155, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'Designation'. Scan count 0, logical reads 237346, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 118673, logical reads 237609, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'CompanyUserDesignation'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'ApplicationUser'. Scan count 637544, logical reads 1354626, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 12, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'ApplicationOrg'. Scan count 0, logical reads 569626, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
Table 'LoanAccounts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4447447, physical reads 14120, read-ahead reads 79730, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: [Put your plan here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: There is a lot of low hanging fruit for performance improvements here. All those subqueries using top 1. Change those to MAX, no need to sort here. The scalar function as a column....ouch. And what is with the ROW_NUMBER? I guess you don't care which row you get as long you get only one? But definitely seeing the execution plan would be a huge step in letting others help.

Comment: Hello Sean, I have added the plan as a dropbox link. Let me know u are able to get to it. I will start cracking on making the top 1 s as MAX right away. Cant do away with the scalar function as of now.And Row_number I am using in the join section for designation

left outer join Designation ds on ds.id=com.DesignationId )x where x.Rn=1

Comment: @scsimon https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkHavT3oM

Comment: Unable to use MAX directy since we have to use group by for every column in the download section. the results arent coming accurately when I do . Any suggestions here?

Comment: You are calling the feedback table in 3 sub queries in your select which require it to be ordered and then again in the main query. its going to have to read the whole table to get that data.  Also index scans arnt always bad - they are sometimes the best way